# Node Promise rejection does not enter catch

Tags: node.js, mongodb, es6-promise

I have a method calling `findByIdAndRemove` on a mongoDB. In case I don't find the id and therefore can't delete it from the DB, I want to throw an error.

Delete dashboard function:

```
deleteDashboard = (id) => {
  return Dashboard.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec((err, dashboard) => {
    if (err) return errorHandler.handle('dashboardService', err);
    if (dashboard === null) return Promise.reject({ status: 404, message: 'not found' });

    return Promise.resolve(dashboard);
  });
};
```

Function call:

```
return dashboardService.deleteDashboard(id)
  .then(dashboard => res.status(200).json(dashboard))
  .catch(error => res.status(error.status).json(error));
```

I don't understand why calling `dashboardService.deleteDashboard` with an id that isn't in the database, doesn't enter the catch. While debugging, I checked that is enters the `if(dashboard === null)` condition and thus calls `Promise.reject()`, but then it enters the `then` instead of the `catch`.

Comment: Try using `throw` instead of `reject`, will work in most cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
return Dashboard.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec((err, dashboard) => {
```

Usually when you use promise you don't pass a callback. Try to change it to

```
deleteDashboard = (id) => {
  return Dashboard.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec()
  .then(dashboard => {
    if (dashboard === null) return Promise.reject({ status: 404, message: 'not found' });
    return dashboard;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return errorHandler.handle('dashboardService', err);
  })
};
```

I tried to keep most the code as it is. Just changed the callback for a promise, and the error handle for a catch.